# Prove the distance function in a metric space is continous

Tags: real-analysis

Note: I have seen a similar question here, but it was proven using topology methods that I have not covered yet in my real analysis course. So I am hoping this isn't just marked duplicate.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $E\subseteq X$. For $x\in X$, define the distance from $x$ to $E$ by $$\text{dist}(x,E) := \inf\{d(x,y) : y\in E\}.$$ 
Prove that dist$(x,E)$ is a continuous function of $x$.

Alright, so I know I need to show that $$(\forall \epsilon>0)( \exists \delta>0)\text{ such that } d(x,a) < \delta \implies d(\text{dist}(x,E),\text{dist}(a,E)) < \epsilon$$ Right?

But $d$ is an unspecified metric, so that's a little confusing. But when I consider that the distance function is merely an infimum of the metric $d$, my intuition says that I should choose $\delta = \epsilon$. But in doing this, I am not sure if my proof even makes sense...I'm sure it's wrong. Please take a look at the problem and tell me how to go about proving this properly. Thanks.

--"proof"--

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta$ such that $\delta = \epsilon$ and suppose $d(b,c) < \delta$ for any $b,c \in X$. Since dist$(x,E):= \inf\{d(x,y) : y\in E\}$, we have dist$(x,E) < d(x,y_1) + \epsilon$ for some $x\in X$, $y_1\in E$, by the definition of infimum. Likewise, dist$(a,E) < d(a,y_2) + \epsilon$ for some $a\in X$ and $y_2\in E$. Since $y_1,y_2\in E\subseteq X$ we have $d(x,y_1) < \delta$ and $d(a,y_2)< \delta$ so that $\text{dist}(x,E)< \delta$ and $\text{dist}(a,E)< \delta$. Then $$\text{dist}(x,E) - \text{dist}(a,E)< \delta - \delta = 0 < \epsilon.$$ Then $$|\text{dist}(x,E) - \text{dist}(a,E)|< \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $dist(x,E) = d(x,x_1)$ and $dist(a,E) = d(a,x_2)$.

Given any $\epsilon > 0$.

When $d(x,x_1) \ge d(a,x_2)$, then

$|d(x,x_1) - d(a,x_2)| \le |d(x,x_2) - d(a,x_2)| \le d(x,a) < \epsilon$.

When $d(x,x_1) < d(a,x_2)$, then

$|d(a,x_2) - d(x,x_1)| \le |d(a,x_1) - d(x,x_1)| \le d(x,a) < \epsilon$.

Then $\exists \delta = \epsilon$, when $d(x,a) < \delta$ we have $|dist(x,E) - dist(a,E)| < \epsilon$.

In your proof, when given $\epsilon > 0$, $dist(x,E) < d(x,y_1) + \epsilon$, but it may not satify $d(x,y_1) < \delta$.

Comment: I didn't understand what happened from the 4th line till 6th line ;_;